# Regular expression in Python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Another question :

I'm trying to search for a specific pattern in a fiel , but I have to deal with the following case :

This line returns a correct interpretation

```
f27 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x27''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

but this one got badly interpreted as x28 is related to the '()' parenthesis

```
f28 = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x28''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unbalanced parenthesis

I tried with several escapes '\' and '/' but no way !

Any solution ?

Thx

Comment: What is `s` equal to? Cold you post an SSCCE?

Comment: Yeah : s is a file put in a variable  : f = open('d:\BB.ki', "rb")
s = f.read()

Answer (score 0):

Try using raw bytestrings. The re module itself understands escape sequences.

```
f28 = re.findall(br'\x03\x00\x00\x28(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```